# Move process to other TTY

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, linux-mint

Is it possible to move a process from one terminal to another in Linux? For example, if I have executed the "top" command via a gnome-terminal window, I want to move the output shown in the gnome-terminal window to a TTY terminal.

Comment: You can try [reptyr](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/), but it's best to use a program like `screen` or `tmux` to avoid the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's too late by the time you've already executed it, but if you recognise in advance that you might want to move it, you can use

```
screen top
```

to run `top`, and then detach from the running process with Ctrl-A and D. After that, you can run

```
screen -r
```

from any terminal on the same machine to reattach.

It's very powerful, and does a lot more than just that.

Comment: Thanks! That was what wanted, too bad that you have to recognise it in advance though..